# How do I display this number pattern in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to display this number pattern:

```
-3  1  5  9
7  12  17
15 21
```

using:

```
int number = __________________; // assign correct initial value
int row, col;

for (row = 1; row <= 3; row++)
{
    // adjust number so it displays the correct first value in the row
    ________________________________________________
    for (col = 1; col <= ___5 - row___; col++)
    {
      cout << setw (5) << number;

     // adjust number so it displays the next correct value in this row 
    ______________________number + row + 3;_________________________________ 
        } / /end inner for loop
 cout << endl;
 } // end outer for loop
```

I know number + row + 3 gets the correct numbers across but I cannot seem to get the correct start value.

Comment: Can you please format your code appropriately and edit the title to a "cleaner" version? Thanks

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Thank you Michael, for fixing that formatting.

Comment: Hint: in all rows there is arithmetic progression. Between two rows there is arithmetic progression with another constant.

Comment: i know that if you were to say (for the start cal)- row * 10 -13 you get -3/7/and 17 for your start values but the problem i keep running into is that from -3 to 7 is 10 and from 7 to 15 is 8 so its wrong. the lines are blanks that i fill in with the corrct code

Comment: @Etienne This looks like some sort of fill in the blank CS homework.

Comment: if this is how kids these days are learning to program, we are doomed

Comment: @ChristianMims23: If you do this with paper and pencil, do you then see what the progressions are and what the logic behind it is?

Comment: @Bart- yes on the first row its adding 4 the second 5 the third 6. Correct?

Comment: In each outer loop number should be abs(number)*2+1, so that gives you -3, 7, 15. In each row the values progress such as number = number + row + 3

Comment: @PeterR.- when i use your number = abs(number)*2+1 and displayed 1, 35, 101 for the start values.

Comment: if anyone is willing to go on skype so I can show you how it displays i am willing to do so

Comment: @slf That's what I initially thought, but is it actually that bad of a learning experience? I would think it's like being given a coworker's broken code and being asked to fix it while making as few changes as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
number = -3

for(row = 1; row <= 3; row++){
   for (col = 0; col < 5 - row; col ++){
       display (number + col * (3 + row));
   }
   number += 12 - row * 2;
}
```

With your restrictions, that would be:

```
int number = 0; // assign correct initial value
int row, col;

for (row = 1; row <= 3; row++)
{
    // adjust number so it displays the correct first value in the row
    number += 12 - (row-1) * 2 - (row+2) * (6 - row);

    for (col = 1; col <= 5 - row; col++)
    {
        cout << setw (5) << number;

        // adjust number so it displays the next correct value in this row 
        number = number + row + 3;
    } / /end inner for loop
    cout << endl;
 } // end outer for loop
```

Explanation:

(not a bullet) + [12 - (row-1)*2] is for moving between -3, 7 and 15

(not a bullet) - [ ((row-1) + 2) * (5 - (row - 1))] is for compensating growth of the number in the internal loop

Since the result of the right part with row = 1 is -3, initial number is chosen as 0.

Comment: @Srv19 the problem is is that i am only allowed to answer within the blanks provided. I have the col formula and the adjustment formula already provided. so really all i need is a start value that produces -3 in the first row 7 in the second and 15 in the third.

Comment: disregard that; number = -15; first blank: number +=12 - (row-1) * 2

Comment: (first blank in the loop, i mean). Second blak in the loop would be number - number + 3 + row, why not

Comment: with number = -15 and first blank being: number+= 12 - (row-1) *2 you do get -3 as your fist value but then you get 23 and 46 for you second and third start values

Comment: The explanation makes it make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = -1; // assign correct initial value 
int row, col;  
for (row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {     
// adjust number so it displays the correct first value in the row
    number -=2;
    for (col = 1; col <= ___5 - row___; col++){       
        cout << setw (5) << number;       
        // adjust number so it displays the next correct value in this row
        ______________________number + row + 3;
    } / /end inner for loop  
    cout << endl;  
} // end outer for loop
```

Comment: @ChristianMims23: Deleted my previous comment and have just edited this answer - does this work (I don't have dev tools on this computer - sorry)

Comment: no the start value answer was number += 12 - (row-1) * 2 - (row+2) * (6 - row); and that displayed the correct start value then with my adjustment it displayed the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  int i,j; 
  int temp=-3;

  for(i=0;i<3;++i)
  {    
      for(j=0;j<4-i;++j)
      {
          cout<<temp<<" ";
          temp=temp+4+i;
      }

      temp=temp-(4+i);
      temp=temp-2;
      cout<<"\n";
  }

  char dd;
  cin>>dd;
  return 2;
}
```

Comment: Cant you adjust the `temp` value in a single statement. Why you need 2 lines of code? `temp=temp-(4+i);    temp=temp-2;`